# Apache Authoization Header Not found Even After .htaccess modification

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, ubuntu

I have a laravel application having .htaccess file as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I am expecting a "Authorization" key in my request headers but its not getting through in my dev server which is running Ubuntu 14.0.4.

Same OS is in my local machine and in local machine it is working perfect.

The only difference between these two environment is in my local machine i have made a VirtualHost where as i cannot make VirtualHost on dev server so i am accessing it via IP Address / projectroot

Comment: is there any different between both phpinfo() result, specially for SERVER ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  ?

Comment: No, both have "keep-alive" value

Answer (score 0):

So Finally i found the reason. It was actually my Apache default configuration file was not allowing my project .htaccess file to overwrite its configurations. That is why the line in .htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

has no effect. To allow so I put that this directive in my apache configuration file in my case its `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                # AllowOverride None (Old value)
                AllowOverride All #(New Value)                   

                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>
```